# How to show Splash screen image after deploy?

Tags: silverlight, image, deployment, screen, splash-screen

I have a 'silverlight RIA' app with a customized splash screen with an image.
Everything seems work fine on my client side.
The problem starts after I deploy it on the server. My image is not shown anymore!
First of all, I had problems with showing the splash screen. But, after I changed the property of 'splashscreen.xaml' to "content" it became OK! But still it doesn't show the image after deploy! 
Any suggestions on what's wrong and how can that be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start the url of the image by ../